# Rpi 3b opencv lines of code not registering

Tags: opencv

I recently installed opencv ans tried to run a simple process some of the commands won't read such as `cv2.imshow() or cv2.imread () along with the waitkey()` everything else works fine but a few necessary likes of code. Is it that i dont have have depencies for them or is it something else?

My code

````
import numpy as np
Import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True)
        #Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        out.write(frame)
        #Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        if cv2.waitkey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
              break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
out.write()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()```
````

Errors i get

````
Traceback  (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/test.py", line 9 in <module>
      out.write(frame)
NameError: 'out' is not defined

Cv2.imshow()
Cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.4) /home/pi/packaging/opencv-python/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:356: error: (-215: assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'```
````

Comment: `some of the commands won't read` What exactly do you mean by that? Do you get an error message? Please add this information to your question.

Comment: Theres ```out.read()``` and it sais that is isn't definined and for ```cv2.imread()``` it sais something about dimensions or coordinates i dont know but i cant really check to be sure because im in school and about to change classes

Comment: You don't have to do it now, but you really have to give more detailed information than just `it sais something about dimensions or coordinates`. Add some problem code and full error messages to your question

Comment: `NameError: 'out' is not defined` Error says it: 'out' needs to be defined first. No idea what it's supposed to do. Did you copy this code from somewhere? Or adapted from an example? If so then please provide a link

Comment: https://youtu.be/QjKmgdrNCP0 it was a test code

Comment: Sorry, I'm bailing out here. I don't do video tutorials. Seems to be a very long one too...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange @Entity. So far, the problem you've described seems to be more of a general programming issue rather than Raspberry Pi-specific. Please don't expect users to go through a whole tutorial to understand what you're trying to do; let alone a video tutorial. It is up to you to clearly describe your issue.

Comment: The error you're getting is `'out' is not defined`. If you look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53532660/opencv-wont-properly-write-to-output-file-python) from another question you'll see that `out` is defined before being used. Something like this: `out = cv2.VideoWriter('test_output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480),0)`

Comment: Ok so now i just get the error for ```cv2.imshow('frame',frame)``` about assertion failure